# Overhang/cantilevered floor insulation

Tags: insulation

I started a job for improving my overhang floor insulation.

I have some questions:

1- Before starting the job I noticed that the plywood closing the underside of the cantilever had 3" hole cut in it. I think it was for blowing the dense packed fiber glass but some holes were not sealed. Is it supposed to be that way? (That’s me that put the mesh to prevent squirrels coming in. I did not know if it was there for venting)

[image]

2- After removing the plywood and the dense packed fibreglass, I discovered a rectangle hole in the wall like 10"x5". Do you have any idea of the purpose of this hole? I think there was an oil tank (removed before I buy the house) for the previous furnace close to that hole.

[image]

3- As you can see my cantilever is not flush with my joist. There is like one feet between the joist and the foundation. I cannot figure what kind of material is between the joist and the foundation. It seems like two joists with something in between (sip : structural insulated panels?). What do you think?

[image]
[image]
[image]

(The drawing represent what I was thinking to do, it was done before I open up the plywood)

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! If you'll spend a moment taking the [tour], you'll note that we're a bit different than most sites. We like _one_ question per question so that you can pick & accept one answer as the most correct one. You've asked three questions that are only related because they happen to be on your project. If you'll please [edit] your question, remove two of them, then post new questions, one for each, that'll help things flow better here, otherwise your question is at risk of getting closed for "needing more focus". We more than welcome multiple questions at once, so no worries there

Comment: @FreeMan I was just wondering if I can split my three questions on the same thread here or if I need to post two more threads (one for each question)

Comment: There are no "threads" here - this isn't a discussion board it's a Question & Answer forum, as noted in the [tour]. Please feel free to have multiple open questions at once, nobody will look askance at you for doing so.